# How to enable pagination for grid in azure workbook?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to **enable pagination for GRID** in azure workbook.
but unfortunately I am unable to do,
So could someone help me for the same?

Steps run the query in workbook.

Go to -  Log Analytics workspace --> Select workbook --> Click on empty workbook (RHS) --> Click on **+ Add** button --> Click on **Add query**
--> Go to query window and type `AppTraces` and run it.
it will return only 250 records in the grid.

**Problem**
We can't see more that 250 records in the grid, so I have to enable pagination for the grid so we can goto any number of record

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks itself does not directly implement paging, as many of the data sources it supports don't themselves support paging.

You *can* see more than 250 rows in a grid if you go to the advanced settings of the step, and change that limit.  the *default* is 250, but the maximum is 10000 rows.